# sequencing/queuing http request batches with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I'm trying to figure out how to queue outgoing api request batches using RxJs.

My goal on [this sample angular app](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-gauss-cfcj0z?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:0-1041) is to simultaneously send out 3 "random-cat-facts" API requests and only once they resolve send out 2 additional "random-activity" requests:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { forkJoin, concat } from "rxjs";
import { combineAll } from "rxjs/operators";

const RANDOM_CAT_FACTS_API = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";
const RANDOM_ACTIVITY_API = "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchSequential() {
    const catFactsObservables = [
      this.http.get(RANDOM_CAT_FACTS_API),
      this.http.get(RANDOM_CAT_FACTS_API),
      this.http.get(RANDOM_CAT_FACTS_API)
    ];

    const activitiesObservables = [
      this.http.get(RANDOM_ACTIVITY_API),
      this.http.get(RANDOM_ACTIVITY_API)
    ];

    const sequencedObservables = [
      forkJoin(catFactsObservables),
      forkJoin(activitiesObservables)
    ];

    concat(sequencedObservables)
      .pipe(combineAll())
      .subscribe((p) => console.log({ p }));
  }
}
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong since currently all 5 requests are sent out simultaneously.

How can I use RxJs in order to send out the `activitiesObservables` requests only once the `catFactsObservables` requests have been resolved?

Additionally, is there a way to get the `subscribe` callback to trigger only once both batches have been resolved - thus containing the responses for all 5 requests and not firing a separate event for each batch?

**Sandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-gauss-cfcj0z?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:700-721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve this based on @gil's answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39359127/10185326) using a combination of `concatAll` and `reduce`.

```
    concat(sequencedObservables)
      .pipe(
        concatAll(),
        reduce((acc, res) => {
          acc.push(res);
          return acc;
        }, [])
      )
      .subscribe((p) => console.log(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

what you have to do is to use concatAll operator instead of combineAll operator.

this way, the second observable won't emit before the first one did.

your code would look like this:

```
concat(sequencedObservables)
      .pipe(concatAll())
      .subscribe((p) => console.log({ p }));
```

Comment: Thanks @gil! This seems to do the trick. But is there a way to get both batch results combined in a single subscribe event? With your solution, the subscribe callback triggers twice and I would like it to trigger only once, when both batches are resolved.
I updated my question.

Comment: Then instead of concat u can use combineLatest operator. It’ll emit only when both observables have emitted

Comment: combineLatest doesn't delay the triggering of the second batch until the first one completes. All 5 requests are sent out together.